# how do i get the information over api of the assumed role?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a function that writes the cost of the account in a CSV. Now I would like to use assumed role to query all other accounts. Unfortunately he only writes the costs of the account where the Lambda function is located. What do I do wrong to write all further costs into the CSV file? Here is the code as I thought it would be. I left the function of the CSV out of the picture, because it works perfectly.

```
import boto3
import re
import csv
import os

def lambda_handler(event,context):

    #get data from environment
    start = os.environ['Start']
    end = os.environ['End']

    response = client.get_cost_and_usage(
        TimePeriod={
            'Start': start,
            'End': end
        },
        Granularity='MONTHLY',
        Metrics=['BlendedCost'],
        GroupBy=[
            {
                'Type': 'TAG',
                'Key': 'Project
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assume the role in the target account first.

1. Assume the cross-account role by using STS to retrieve temporary credentials.
2. Create a boto3 session using these credentials.
3. Fetch a client using this session.

The following function handles steps 1 and 2.

```
def assume_role(aws_account_number, role_name):
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

    partition = sts_client.get_caller_identity()['Arn'].split(":")[1]

    response = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn='arn:{}:iam::{}:role/{}'.format(
            partition,
            aws_account_number,
            role_name
        ),
        RoleSessionName='MySession'
    )

    # Create a boto3 session by using the temporary credentials
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken']
    )

    print("Assumed session for {}.".format(aws_account_number))

    return session
```

The last step is to get your client using this session.

```
session = assume_role('123456789012', 'MyCrossAccountRoleName')
client = session.client('ce')
```

It is always a good idea to increase the [default Lambda timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html) of 3 seconds when making cross-account requests.